# reading the values inside fscanf gives different values when reading outside?

Tags: c

I couldnt find anything simular to this, I appologise in advance if maybe something similar was asked.

You would expect the values printed inside the fscanf to be exactly the same outside, however this is not the case.
The values for &specread->superVisorRating[i] are fine, while the values of &specread->superVisorRating[i] are different.

```
int read_Supervisors(char fileName[], spec *specread){
int i=0;

FILE *supervisors = fopen(fileName, "r");
if(supervisors == NULL){
    printf("Error opening supervisors input file name %s", fileName);
    }else
    // Read the names and numbers and store them in an array.
    while(fscanf(supervisors, "%s %d", &specread->superVisorRating[i], &specread->superVisorRating[i]) !=EOF){
        printf("before y %s y \n", &specread->superVisorNames[i]);
        i++;

    }
    for(int j=0; j<i;j++){
printf("After y %s y\n", &specread->superVisorNames[j]);
    }
fclose(supervisors);
    // Return the number of runs the loop went through to read the names if required, this is system allows you to place more than 4 supervisors.
return i;}
```

Program output:

```
before y Bob y
before y Sally y
before y Jian y
before y Hecctor y
After y BSJHecctor y
After y SJHecctor y
After y JHecctor y
After y Hecctor y
```

The formate of the file is this.

```
Bob 67
Sally 78
Jian 69
Hecctor 89
```

I am expecting the values to be the same regardless where they are printed from as they are passed as pointers.
for debugging I am just clueless where to start, tried googling tried different loops tried editing the file, tried increasing the array from 40 to 100.

Edit: Here is the minimal code to replicate the issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct spec{
    char name[100];
    float width;
    float height;
    float depth;
    char material[100];
    char superVisorNames[40];
    int superVisorRating[40];
}spec;

int read_Supervisors(char fileName[], spec *specread){
    int i=0;

    FILE *supervisors = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if(supervisors == NULL){
        printf("Error opening supervisors input file name %s", fileName);
    }else
        // Read the names and numbers and store them in an array.
        while(fscanf(supervisors, "%s %d", &specread->superVisorNames[i], &specread->superVisorRating[i]) !=EOF){
            printf("before y %s y \n", &specread->superVisorNames[i]);
            i++;

        }
    for(int j=0; j<i;j++){
        printf("After y %s y\n", &specread->superVisorNames[j]);
    }
    fclose(supervisors);
    // Return the number of runs the loop went through to read the names if required, this is system allows you to place more than 4 supervisors.
    return i;
}
int main() {
    spec spec1;
    read_Supervisors("builders.dat", &spec1);

    return 0;
}
```

The builders.dat file that i am reading has 4 supervisors and each got their own rating. The exact content in the file is above.

Comment: Strangely, you are getting the initial letters and then a partial overwrite. Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows the problem (including library headers and `struct` definitions).

Comment: You have `&specread->superVisorRating[i]` for **both** of the `fscanf` arguments. You then print from `&specread->superVisorNames[i]` which you have not entered, and the `&` is also (probably) incorrect.

Comment: Aside: the `while(fscanf(. . .) !=EOF)` here should be `while(fscanf(. . .) == 2)`

Comment: *for debugging I am just clueless where to start* - begin with the compiler warnings, and carefully reading through the code line by line.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal Complete Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Providing the necessary details, including your MCRE, compiler warnings and associated errors, and sample data if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: `&specread->superVisorNames[i]` is wrong. `char superVisorNames[40];` so you read into `specread->superVisorNames` (it's already a pointer through array/pointer conversion C Standard 6.3.2.1)

Comment: Thanks for the update: with these members `char superVisorNames[40]; int superVisorRating[40];` are you expecting one supervisor with 40 ratings, or 40 supervisors each with their own rating?

Comment: The cite is [C18 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2596.pdf#subsection.6.3.2)

Comment: Your superVisorNames are overlapping; that's the simplest explanation for this weird output. You probably goofed up when initializing `specread`. Can you share the code that does this initialization?

Comment: You only have one struct: `spec spec1;` I suppose you need an **array** of them? This `&specread->superVisorNames[i]` is overwriting the same string at successive index positions.

Comment: @WeatherVane, I do not need an array of spec, but why would it be overwriting the same string?

Comment: @RuudHelderman, I just declare it, spec spec1;

Comment: @DanielBoos Please be aware `char superVisorNames[40];` does not allocate an array of 40 strings; it defines a single string of length 40.

Comment: ...and then `specread->superVisorNames[0]` is the first **character**, `specread->superVisorNames[1]` is the second, and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh Boy, you are really confused on reading multiple values into an *Array of Struct* -- you have only a single struct, but attempt to read multiple values into it. That won't work. It looks like you want:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX     100   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXNAME  40

typedef struct spec{
  char name[MAX];
  float width;
  float height;
  float depth;
  char material[MAX];
  char superVisorNames[MAXNAME];
  int superVisorRating;
} spec;

/* open filename reading into specread array, returns number
 * of elements filled on success, -1 otherwise.
 */
int read_Supervisors (char *fileName, spec *specread)
{
  int i=0;

  FILE *supervisors = fopen(fileName, "r");
  
  if (supervisors == NULL) {    /* validate file open for reading */
    perror ("fopen-supervisors");
    return -1;
  }
  /* Read the names and numbers and store them in an array.
   * Protect array bounds. Field-width modifier required when
   * reading into character array (39 below)
   */
  while (i < MAX && fscanf (supervisors, "%39s %d", 
                            specread[i].superVisorNames, 
                            &specread[i].superVisorRating) == 2) {
    i++;
  }
  
  fclose(supervisors);
  
  /* return number of supervisors */
  return i;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
  spec spec1[MAX] = {{ .name = "" }};   /* initialize array all 0 */
  int n = 0;
  
  if (argc < 2) { /* validate 1 argument given for filename */
    puts ("usage: ./program filename");
    return 0;
  }
  
  /* read file, validate return */
  if ((n = read_Supervisors (argv[1], spec1)) == -1) {
    return 1;
  }
  
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { /* output results */
    printf ("sup: %-12s    rating: %d\n", 
            spec1[i].superVisorNames, spec1[i].superVisorRating);
  }
}
```

Problems corrected:

1. you need an array of `spec`, not a pointer to one,
2. you need a single `int` for `superVisorRating`, not 40,
3. when you pass the array, it decays (is converted to) a pointer to the first element in the array [C18 Standard - 6.3.2.1(p3)](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2596.pdf#subsection.6.3.2)
4. you compare the return of `fscanf()` to the number of conversions that successfully took place (e.g. `== 2` -- the *match-count*), not `EOF`,
5. you need a return value to indicate error from `read_Supervisors()`, and `-1` is fine, a positive return being the number of array elements filled.,
6. there is no `else` needed, if `fopen()` fails, return at that point and save the level of indentation from then on,
7. you must validate the return from the call to `read_Supervisors()` in `main()`,
8. don't hardcode filenames -- that is what `int argc, char **argv` arguments to `main()` are for `:)`. You shouldn't need to recompile to read from a different filename.

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in file `dat/sups.txt`, you would have:

```
$ ./bin/readsups dat/sups.txt
sup: Bob             rating: 67
sup: Sally           rating: 78
sup: Jian            rating: 69
sup: Hecctor         rating: 89
```

---

**Multiple Supervisors per `struct spec`**

If you have multiple supervisors you need to track per `struct spec`, you can create another struct, say `struct sups` to hold the `superVisorNames[]` and `superVisorRatings` members and then include an array of `struct sups` in `struct spec`. You should also capture the number of supervisor elements filled in your array of `struct sups` as a member of `struct spec` (say `nsups`). Putting that together you could do:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC   1024   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAX     100
#define MAXNAME  40
#define MAXSUPS  10

typedef struct sups {
  char superVisorNames[MAXNAME];
  int superVisorRating;
} sups;

typedef struct spec {
  char name[MAX];
  float width;
  float height;
  float depth;
  char material[MAX];
  int nsups;
  sups supers[MAXSUPS];
} spec;

/* open filename reading into specread array, returns number
 * of elements filled on success, -1 otherwise.
 */
int read_Supervisors (char *fileName, spec *specread)
{
  char buf[MAXC];
  FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
  
  if (fp == NULL) {    /* validate file open for reading */
    perror ("fopen-supervisors");
    return -1;
  }
  /* Read the names and numbers and store them in an array.
   * Protect array bounds. Field-width modifier required when
   * reading into character array (39 below)
   */
  while (specread->nsups < MAXSUPS && fgets (buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
    if (sscanf (buf, "%39s %d", 
                specread->supers[specread->nsups].superVisorNames, 
                &specread->supers[specread->nsups].superVisorRating) == 2) {
      specread->nsups += 1;
    }
  }
  
  fclose (fp);
  
  /* return number of supervisors */
  return specread->nsups;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
  spec spec1 = { .name = "" };   /* initialize array all 0 */
  
  if (argc < 2) { /* validate 1 argument given for filename */
    puts ("usage: ./program filename");
    return 0;
  }
  
  /* read file, validate return */
  if (read_Supervisors (argv[1], &spec1) == -1) {
    return 1;
  }
  
  for (int i = 0; i < spec1.nsups; i++) { /* output results */
    printf ("sup: %-12s    rating: %d\n", 
            spec1.supers[i].superVisorNames, 
            spec1.supers[i].superVisorRating);
  }
}
```

(use/output is the same)

Let me know if you have other questions.

Comment: Thank you so much David, I just have a few questions if you do not mind. Why is it that I need an array of spec when spec has an array `superVisorNames`. Even without an array `superVisorNames` worked perfectly but why is that?

Comment: You are welcome, check out the update, I added more (and important array bounds checks). Good luck with your coding. Ask away, more than happy to help further.

Comment: Last edit was format clean-up with comment for function added, no logic changes.

Comment: Cheers David, I appericate your help C:

Comment: Sure, only other change I would make would be to read a line at-a-time into a buffer and parse the buffer with `sscanf()` rather than a direct read with `fscanf()`. That way if there was a line with bad format -- (return `!= 2`), then that line is simply skipped instead of breaking your read from that point on. E.g. `char buf[1024];` then just read with `while (i < MAX && fgets (buf, sizeof buf, supervisors) { if (sscanf (buf, "%39s %d", specread[i].superVisorNames, &specread[i].superVisorRating) == 2) { i++; }}`. Your read and parse are decoupled.

Comment: And an entire line of data is consumed each read with no possibility of offending characters being left in `supervisors` unread in the event of a *matching-failure* with `fscanf()`.

Comment: Thanks again David, I might do that as well, I have a question regarding best practise. Since I am making an array of spec which reserves memory of the other values times the size of the array. Would it be better if `superVisorsNames` were a 2d array, or is it really not that big of a deal?

Comment: No. When you create any "object", ideally you want that object to be able to stand on its own, be one of a collection, etc... The base of your object is `struct spec`. If your `struct spec` is supposed to have multiple supervisors and multiple ratings, then consider creating a `struc sup { int rating; char supName[MAXNAME]; }` and make  `struct spec` contain an array type `struc sup[how-many]`. That way each `struct spec` and `struct sup` define one object. You just have multiple `struct sup` in one `struct spec`. Otherwise, just using `struct spec` for the base is fine.

Comment: I ended up doing just that which lowered the bytes of memory used by the array from ~1300 to ~200 bytes. Now I have a question, would it also be possible to do it with a 2d array? 
have ``char superVisorsNames[MAXNAMES][5]`` in the original ``struct spec`` store each name in the rows, the more to the next col to store the next name. or is something like that bad practise due to the complexity it may adds?

Comment: I'll drop an update you can compare with.

Comment: Now updated to read with `fgets()` and parse with `sscanf()`. Meaning you can add a line `"bananas"` in the middle of your data file and the program will read and ignore it just fine. (now try that with `fscanf()` -- things don't go so well from the point of matching-failure on... unless you manually extract the offending characters from your input buffer through the end-of-line after each failure) `sed '2abananas' oldfile.txt > newfile.txt` will put `bananas` in the middle of (after line 2) of `newfile.txt` to test `:)`